# Is there a way of grouping geometry nodes input fields in foldouts in the UI?

Tags: interface, geometry-nodes

Is there a way of grouping inputs in the Properties Panel into foldouts? I'm creating a huge geometry node graph with a lot of inputs and things are becoming a little out of hand.

[image: A huge input node]

Answer (score 4):

Not yet, but the need for more advanced options like collapsible sub-panels and sockets for dynamic options (checkmarks for *Switch* node inputs instead of the current `0 | 1` slider, for instance) has been a topic of discussion in the community for the last few months and after *BCON22* [they've posted a roadmap/to-do list sort of thing](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/2022-10-31-geometry-nodes-post-bcon22-workshop/26491#menu-switch-enum-17), which includes a first draft for complex nodes and node groups, pictured below. Notice the "Advanced" foldout.

How long before it is available to use is another matter, obviously.

[image]

Comment: I see what they're doing. I'm more concerned with the properties panel, though. That's the UI I'm gonna use when my pipeline is finished.

Comment: I believe it's part of the same project—they share basically the same infrastructure after all, and people complaining about how insufficient Group output panel options (i.e. Properties interface) felt was the whole reason it became a topic in the first place (since so many Geometry Nodes setups started being made).